# Get value from each select multiple which have same name using php

Tags: php, html, jquery

HTML :

```
...
<form method="post">
 <tr>
  <td>
   <input type="text" name="text[]">
   <select name="list[]" multiple>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
   </select>
  </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>
   <input type="text" name="text[]">
   <select name="list[]" multiple>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
   </select>
  </td>
 </tr> 
 ... and another row addition using jquery dynamic rows.
 <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

PHP :

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
 $cnt = count($_POST['text']); 
 for($i=0;$i<$cnt;$i++) {
   echo $_POST['text'][$i];            //correct code 
   foreach ($_POST['list'] as $item) { //wrong code!  
    echo $item;                        //wrong code! 
  }                                    //wrong code!
 }  
}
?>
//note: "wrong code!" generate all $_POST['list'] should be each $_POST['list'][$i]
```

I'm stuck on wrong code above, how to get each $_POST['list'][$i] value ?.
Note: for certain reason we can't use auto increment ID if needed for each select element, unique random ID seems ok.

Comment: If you are not sure about the actual structure of the data you received, then to a `var_dump($_POST);` first.

Comment: You say "wrong code" but you don't explain what actually happens. Wrong in what sense? Do you get error messages? Wrong data? Computer catches fire?

Comment: One issue with your form is that all select's are multi-choice so having them with the same name `list[]` will send all selected options in one single array so you won't know what option was selected for which text. There's no reference. So your PHP code would just echo all selected options over and over on each iteration of your `for`-loop.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson, sorry for not being clear, english not my primary language, wrong code because what i need is like question at bottom, "how to get each $_POST['list'][$i] value ?" the wrong code above generate all $_POST, not value for each loop.

Comment: You can group your form items to know what belongs to what. Something like: `name="text[something]"` and then `list[something]` for the select. Then you just change "something" for the next text-select pair. The `something` can be a random string. The important part is to have the same for each text-select-pair.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson, thank you for guide, i really don't how to implement that, finally end up with other solution from https://github.com/amsify42/jquery.amsify.suggestags, same result, easier on coding.